# How to check corrupt image when it uploads?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a project for the Indian government. The issue was that is how to check corrupt images and PDF when user upload image or PDF. Suppose if user can change extension of file from .txt to .jpg then its uploaded then it uploads. So I want to disable if someone upload file with change extension or corrupt image or PDF.

Comment: For images i have write codes which are as follow:- var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
    var file, img;


    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);


    }

});

Comment: But for corrupt pdf i didn't get how to check ? can any one help

Comment: are you looking for corrupt image or corrupt pdf?

Comment: I have done for corrupt image and looking for corrupt pdf if some one change extension from .txt to .pdf and then upload then how to check it?

Comment: As far as I know, checking if a pdf actually is a pdf can only be done on server side. You could try and open it with text or something similar
it throws some sort of exception when you try opening or modifying something else then a PDF. 
Then you can handle that pdf exception and validate upload.

Comment: Ok thanks hiren. and by the way who can vote this question as -1. If this not research effort then write code in javascript to check validation

Comment: I don't know buddy but your question does not show research effort because developers require something that hasn't been discovered.

Comment: Are you looking for client or server side validation? There is no much you can do at client (JS) side beside using (subset) of PDF.js. On server side, you can use any native pdf tool (e.g. pdftk) or PDF.js via node.

Answer (score 1):

More simple solution and if you don't care whether file is corrupted or not. You can check first 2-8 bytes and determine if it's a file type you can support (see [Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))), e.g.

- PNG starts with `0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47 0x0D 0x0A 0x1A 0x0A`
- JPG `0xFF 0xD8`
- PDF `0x25 0x50 0x44 0x46`

Comment: See how to read into Uint8Array https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/2170eda9df013119835a21d5194e6d986397f4ac/web/app.js#L1777-L1784

Answer (score 0):

Try using PDF.js which raise exception when you will going to read non-PDF file and you can use that API to check whether your file is actual PDF and not no PDF.

Always be clear that checking PDF file requires reading content of the file and validate it's format you don't have to read PDF just check the PDF format.

[PDF.JS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)

Comment: you can try live demo on github and try loading non pdf file.

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html check this link and upload non pdf by changing extension.

Comment: You don't have to use entire PDF.js viewer to do validation. Just core library will be enough. PDF.js modular, so you even reduce its size to just basic parser, e.g. you don't need image and font conversion stuff.